# Changing ECC code of a block

Tags: c++, c

can I change the ECC code for a block of a file stored on a flash drive by any means ?
 of a file stored on a HDD (though I don't think there would be a difference between the two)

Maybe , through some hardware interrupts or anything like that?

Also I need the solution to be in C/C++.

Comment: If someone is still unclear I am talking about ECC code in a flash drive http://www.eurekatech.com/products/memory/NAND_Flash_faq.htm#11 as example

Answer (score 1):

A NAND flash drive is composed of a number of data pages and a flash controller. The ECC code on the NAND flash is used by the flash controller.  The controller uses it to determine if the associated data page has any errors.  A filesystem (like fat32, NTFS, or ext3) is usually implemented on top of the raw data page structure. A file may be spread across one or more flash pages.  Please note that there is an error code for each flash page, meaning that a file larger than one data page will have an error code for each page it uses.  A hard disk drive is composed of one or more platters, heads which read and write data on the platters, and a disk controller.  Each platter is divided into sectors. Hard disk drives also have error codes to check the integrity of sectors on the platters. Again, a filesystem, is typically implemented on top of the raw disk sectors. If a file is larger than a sector then there will be multiple sectors associated with the file, each sector having its own error code. To access a data page or sector error code you will need to interface with the flash or hard dive controller directly. This will require interfacing with the device driver for the device. You will need to read the documentation for the device driver in order to discover what functions it offers to allow you access to error codes. In either instance, unless a file occupies only one data page or sector it will have more than one error code associated with it. Some filesystems create error codes for files, regardless of there length, but accessing a filesystem level error code typically does not require hardware access.